# ADAL in Nativescript for Angular

Tags: angular, nativescript, adal

I have a working Angular 8 solution with ADAL login using 3rd party library, https://www.npmjs.com/package/adal-angular4

Now I want to make the same in nativescript.
I have tried different ADAL libraries, but none of them seems to match.

My configuration looks like this

```
const environment = {  
  config: {
    tenant: '123456789',
    clientId: '123456',
    apikey: '123456',
    redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/authenticate',
    endpoints: {
      'https://graph.microsoft.com': '12345',
      'https://someotherurl': 'https://blabla'      
    }
  }
};
```

I have looked at this
https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-azure-auth

but can't seem to figure how to have multiple resources. Also the redirecturl, I don't quite understand

This is what I have done so far

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AzureAuth } from 'nativescript-azure-auth';

const authority = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + environment.config.tenant ;
const clientID = environment.config.clientId;
const resourceId = '123456';
const redirectUri = 'https://asd/authenticate';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class AdalService {
  azureAuth: AzureAuth;

  constructor() {
    this.azureAuth = new AzureAuth(authority, clientID, resourceId, redirectUri);
  }

  login() {
    this.azureAuth.login()
      .then(accessToken => {
          console.log(`Token: ${accessToken}`);
      })
      .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

It doesn't complain, but it doesn't look right. For example I am not asked to consent on login

Comment: I'm not a microsoft person, but did you give a try for [nativescript-oauth2](https://github.com/alexziskind1/nativescript-oauth2), I hope that provides what you are looking for.

Comment: I will try this

Comment: @Johansrk Any update for this issue?